# How to create monthly candlestick chart using daily data?

Tags: highcharts, candlestick-chart

Is there a way to create monthly candlesticks using daily data in `highcharts`

for example, I have daily close price as follows.

```
    [

[1270425600000,33.57],
[1270512000000,34.03],
[1270598400000,34.25],
[1270684800000,34.35],
[1270771200000,34.49],
[1271030400000,34.60],
[1271116800000,34.55],
[1271203200000,35.04],
[1271289600000,35.11],
[1271376000000,35.51],
[1271635200000,35.29],
[1271721600000,35.51], etc
```

I want to create monthly candles based on that. Is there a way to do it with highcharts? Appreciate any help.

Comment: This documentation ought to be helpful. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/chart-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highstock has data grouping feature - [series.dataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.area.dataGrouping) - and you can set options, so the data will be grouped into 1 month interval.

```
series: [{
   type: 'candlestick',
   name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
   data: data,
   dataGrouping: {
     forced: true,
     units: [
       ['month', 1]
     ]
   }
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/uyrz7bz1/